# Finding all kendo drop downs on page

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'd like to create reusable code to find each kendoDropDown on my page and set an event handler on it.  Here's code that finds a single kendoDrop down and does what i want:

```
       var cb = $("#myID").data("kendoDropDownList");
       console.log("cb: " + cb);
       if (cb)
            cb.close();
```

What I need is code that finds every kendoDropDown on the page and adds the same event handler to each.  I've tried

```
        $("input").each(function (index, element) {
           if (element) {
               var cb = element.data("kendoDropDownList");
               if (cb) {
               console.log("element: " + element);
               element.close();
               }
           }
       });
```

but clearly i'm missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `element` parameter is a DOM object, not a jQuery object, so you'll have to wrap it again; also, you'd need to call `cb.close()` instead of `element.close()` (or bind to `cb`, since you want to add an event handler). You can also simply reference `this` instead of the `element` parameter:

```
var handler = function (e) {
    console.log("open");
};

$("input").each(function () {
    var cb = $(this).data("kendoDropDownList");
    if (cb) {
        // attach handler to cb
        cb.bind("open", handler)
    }
});
```

Comment: That's mostly right, but it's going to find every `<input>` on the page. I've found that I can use the selector `$(".k-dropdown > input")`, which restricts it to Kendo drop down lists. I don't require the `if` statement, either.